# Problem with Mass Registration

Tags: civievent

There is no option to "Add Contacts To Event" once multiple contacts are selected from a specific event. How do I make this option available?

Comment: hi courtney - it would be really helpful if you acknowledged and/or accepted answers provided by volunteers

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary group, add the selected contacts first to a group and after that go to search, select the contacts in temporary group and add the contacts to the event

Comment: I think you meant 'temporary' and have edited your answer accordingly.  I hope that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue.  Look for "Register participants for event" instead.